# The right way to access a Vue variable from a class method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my code:

```html
<div id='R'> {{ y.vmx() }} </div>

<script>
    class Test {
      vmx() {
        return vm.x
      }
    }

    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#R',
      data: {
        x: 11,
        y: new Test()
      }
    })
</script>
```

This error pops up:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined at Test.vmx ((index):18)`

How can I access a Vue variable inside a class method? (Vue v2.6.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the template is loaded **before** `vm` is assigned, so `vm` is `undefined` in the `Test` class. Ideally, this circular dependency should be avoided in your code design, but there are a couple workarounds.

**OPTION 1:** Defer any references to `vm` inside `Test` until after the initial template is loaded.

For example, set a `ready` flag in the [next tick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) **after** the component has [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted), and then use the flag to [conditionally render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-if) the template parts that require access to `vm`:

```js
class Test {
  vmx() {
    return vm.x
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    x: 2,
    y: new Test(),
    ready: false,
  }),
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()
    this.ready = true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-if="ready">{{ y.vmx() }}</p>
</div>
```

**OPTION 2:** Pass a reference to the `vm` when instantiating `Test`

```js
class Test {
  constructor(vm) {
    this.vm = vm
  }
  
  vmx() {
    return this.vm.x
  }
}

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      x: 2,
      y: new Test(this),
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ y.vmx() }}</p>
</div>
```